# Build HiddenFor's for expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to create an extension that I can call like so

@Html.HiddenForSuperComplex(x => x.Abc)

I want it to recursively loop through the properties for that model/expression and create Hiddens for all the fields in that model/expression so that the model will be preserved.

I've hit a roadblock with the following line:

```
str = htmlHelper.HiddenForComplex<TProperty,mt>(a.Expression);
```

But I'm starting to think I'm going down the wrong path...

```
    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForSuperComplex<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        TProperty t = htmlHelper.GetValue(expression);
        Type type = typeof(TProperty);
        MvcHtmlString retVal = new MvcHtmlString("");


        var newExpression = expression.Body as NewExpression;
        TModel model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;

        foreach (MemberExpression a in newExpression.Arguments)
        {
            Type mt = a.Member.GetType();
            MvcHtmlString str;
            if (ModelUtil.IsSimpleEnough(mt))
            {
                string value = Convert.ToString(GetPropertyValue<TModel>(model, a));
                str = htmlHelper.Hidden(value);
            }
            else
            {
                str = htmlHelper.HiddenForComplex<TProperty,mt>(a.Expression);   //DOES NOT COMPILE
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private static object GetPropertyValue<T>(T instance, MemberExpression me)
    {
        object target;

        if (me.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
        {
            // If the current MemberExpression is at the root object, set that as the target.            
            target = instance;
        }
        else
        {
            target = GetPropertyValue<T>(instance, me.Expression as MemberExpression);
        }

        // Return the value from current MemberExpression against the current target
        return target.GetType().GetProperty(me.Member.Name).GetValue(target, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForComplex<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        TProperty t = htmlHelper.GetValue(expression);
        Type type = typeof(TProperty);
        MvcHtmlString retVal = new MvcHtmlString("");

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in t.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            string value = info.GetValue(t).ToString();
            //string value = (string)type.GetProperty(info.ToString()).GetValue(t, null);
            MvcHtmlString str = htmlHelper.Hidden(value);
            retVal = Concat(retVal, str);

        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: Do you also intend to handle `IEnumerable` properties in the object graph?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I wasn't planning on it, but it certainly would be nice to have

Comment: Looks like you are trying to reinvent the `ViewState` that we were so happy to get rid of in the WebForms world :-) What's the point of all this? A single `id` property should be more than enough. Bear in mind that it is not recommended to be sending model fields from the client that are not intended to be modified by the end user as hidden fields. It would be far more efficient to retrieve those values from the backend datastore on postback and only work with the model values that are really visible and needed.

Comment: Agreed. Seems like this is meant as a way to post back all the properties on a class, even when they aren't being modified in the form. That's not how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: While I appreciate the advice, I still need to do it like this for the time being until I can setup a framework that will send only what is needed and nothing else, which you'll have to just believe me when I say is easier said than done *in my specific situation*

Comment: Do you consider having circular reference in the model graph?

Comment: @VasylZvarydchuk No I did not. But this is meant as a temporary solution until I can develop a framework that will work for my situation, so I will just have to trust myself to not do that

Comment: Simple solution could be serializing your model into a JSON (using Json.NET for example ) and sending it as one hidden value. Then on server you can deserialize it manually. BUT I do agree with @DarinDimitrov comment